# Extracting an Excel file stored in infopath form/XML-file using c#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, base64

I have been assign to make a program automatically reading in infopath forms from users and inserting the input to a database. This form includes a possibility to insert a ".xlsx" file with relevant information. When I investigate the XML file generated from the form the Excel element looks the following (base64 encoding if my research is correct):

```
<AttachedExcelFile>x0lGQRQAAA...[9kb of data]....vd29ya3
```

I have made a program that extracts the relevant input given a path to an excel file. But I need the previous step for extracting the excel file from the infopath to be saved in readable excel format. Such that the other path of the code can be executed.

So any ideas to how to extract the excel file from the XML document and save it as a xlsx file for further processing?

Comment: You *do* know that Infopath was discontinued years ago? I think the last version came out in 2013. Plus you aren't meant to read the raw XML, you should use its SDK to read the elements. `XLSX` is a zipped package of XML files in any case. If this *is* the base64 form of that file, you can save it to disk without modifications.

Comment: Try `byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);` Once you have the byte array you can save it to a file with the `.xlsx` extension. Or you can use EPPLus to read it and process the data, eg `using(var ms=new MemoryStream(data) using (var package = new ExcelPackage()){ var sheet=package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];...}`
{

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this tomorrow when I have the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the decoder program in this link.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2517906/how-to-encode-and-to-decode-a-file-attachment-programmatically-by-usin]

My solution involved directly extracting the string from the XML/infopath file and using the "InfoPathAttachmentDecoder" class to decode and save the file.